# vb.net Object Initialiser List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I have been looking at some C# code:

```
List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>{
    new Employee{firstname="Aamir",lastname="Hasan",age=20},
    new Employee{firstname="awais",lastname="Hasan",age=50},
    new Employee{firstname="Bill",lastname="Hasan",age=70},
    new Employee{firstname="sobia",lastname="khan",age=80},  
    };
```

Now when I convert this to vb.net

```
Dim Employees as List(Of Employee) = New List(Of Employee)() With { New Employee() With { _  
.firstname = "Aamir", _  
.lastname = "Hasan", _   
.age = 20 _  
}, _  
New Employee() With { _  
.firstname = "awais", _  
.lastname = "Hasan", _  
.age = 50 _  
}, _  
New Employee() With { _  
.firstname = "Bill", _  
.lastname = "Hasan", _  
.age = 70 _  
}, _  
New Employee() With { _  
.firstname = "sobia", _  
.lastname = "khan", _  
.age = 80 _  
} _  
}
```

I get the error "Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with'.'."

Now I can get an array of employee using the code:

```
Dim Employees = { New Employee() With { _  
.FirstName = "Aamir", _  
.LastName = "Hasan", _   
.Age = 20}, _  
New Employee() With { _    
.FirstName = "Awais", _   
.LastName = "Hasan", _  
.Age = 50}, _
New Employee() With { _
.FirstName = "Bill", _ 
.LastName = "Hasan", _  
.Age = 70 _
} _  
}
```

But I would like a `List(Of Employee)` as it is bugging me as to why this doesnt work in vb.net?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT** *(2)*
As pointed out in comments, [VB.NET collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) have now been introduced, and a lot of the following post should be considered obsolete.

**EDIT**
[Don't always blindly trust the C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)
<s>[Here's a handy tool for online conversion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)</s>

Turns out [VB.NET doesn't have collection initializers](http://www.cynotwhynot.com/blog/post/Does-VBNET-have-Collection-Initializers.aspx). Which means there is no equivalence of

```
var myList = new List<string>()
{
   "abc",
   "def"
};
```

... but it *does* have object initializers. So you can create an instance of a class and assign values to its properties all in one go, but you cannot create an instance of a list and add items to it all in one go.

There closest you can get is in the link above. You can create an *Array* and add items to it in a single operation, and then you have to `ToList` that array.

So this time I've actually compiled the code myself, and it works. Sorry for the hassle

```
    Dim EmployeesTemp As Employee() = { _
        New Employee() With { _
            .firstname = "Aamir", _
            .lastname = "Hasan", _
            .age = 20 _
        }, _
        New Employee() With { _
            .firstname = "awais", _
            .lastname = "Hasan", _
            .age = 50 _
        }, _
        New Employee() With { _
            .firstname = "Bill", _
            .lastname = "Hasan", _
            .age = 70 _
        }, _
        New Employee() With { _
            .firstname = "sobia", _
            .lastname = "khan", _
            .age = 80 _
        } _
    }

    Dim Employees as List(Of Employee) = EmployeesTemp.ToList()
```

Comment: Sorry this still gives the same error.

Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with'.'.

I used that handy tool when converting it originally :) always use that.

Comment: @JimJams: hah! that had me doing some research alright. i'd say it's time you join the C# side. but hey, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks David, this works a treat, and yes, it is time I joined the C# side!

Comment: Collection initialisers were added in [VB.Net 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx). The equivalent to your C# collection initialiser is `Dim myList = New List(Of String) From { "abc", "def" }`

Comment: It would be very good of you to put an edit to the top of your answer that collection initializers were added in 2010.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

Collection initialisers were [added in VB.NET 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx). This is air code, but here goes:

```
Dim Employees as List(Of Employee) = New List(Of Employee)() From
{ 
    New Employee() With { _   
       .firstname = "Aamir", _
       .lastname = "Hasan", _ 
       .age = 20 _   
    }, _
   New Employee() With { _  
       .firstname = "awais", _  
       .lastname = "Hasan", _ 
       .age = 50 _ 
    }, _ 
   New Employee() With { _ 
       .firstname = "Bill", _ 
       .lastname = "Hasan", _ 
       .age = 70 _ 
    }, _  
   New Employee() With { _ 
       .firstname = "sobia", _ 
       .lastname = "khan", _ 
       .age = 80 _ 
    } _ 
}
```

Comment: VB2010 can also sometimes detect line continuations automatically, so it's possible the underscores are also unnecessary

Comment: I thought you always needed those?

Comment: @codeblend In some cases, if you omit the line-continuation character, the Visual Basic compiler will implicitly continue the statement on the next line of code. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ba9sxbw4.aspx)

Comment: Is there any performance difference between this and just doing `New List(Of Employee)({ ...new employee code here... })`?

Comment: @ps2goat I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Dim Employees As List(Of Employee) = { _
  New Employee() With { .firstname = "Aamir", .lastname = "Hasan", .age = 20 }, _
  New Employee() With { .firstname = "awais", .lastname = "Hasan", .age = 50 }, _
  New Employee() With { .firstname = "Bill",  .lastname = "Hasan", .age = 70 }, _
  New Employee() With { .firstname = "sobia", .lastname = "khan",  .age = 80 } _
}.ToList()
```