# VB equivalent of this C# short-hand snippet

Tags: c#, vb.net

I would like to know if there is a method to write the below code in VB. ( Right now the equivalent VB.NET code looks too verbose )

```
List<DemoUsers> users = new List<DemoUsers>();
users.Add(new DemoUsers
{
    UserName = "name1",
    UserAddress = "Address1"
});
```

Right now I am writing it in VB.NET like

```
Dim users As New List(Of DemoUsers)

Dim usr1 As New DemoUsers()
usr1.UserName = "name1"
usr1.UserAddress = "Address1"

users.Add(usr1)
```

Does VB.NET have an equivalent C# short-hand? Also whats this short-hand method in C# called.

P.S: Could not google this short-hand notation availability as I dont know whats it called. Is there a name to call it?

Comment: It is called Object Initializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx

Comment: @mbeckish: thank you mate. now I know the name. :) thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), which [also exists in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx):

```
New DemoUsers With { .UserName = "name1", .UserAddress = "Address1" }
```

Note that your C# could be even cleaner if you also use a *collection initialzer*:

```
var users = new List<DemoUsers>
{
    new DemoUsers { UserName = "name1", UserAddress = "Address1" }
};
```

And yes, [collection initializers exist in VB too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at the [`With` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283749/the-vb-net-with-statement-embrace-or-avoid):

```
Dim usr1 As New DemoUsers()

With usr1
    .UserName = "name1"
    .UserAddress = "Address1"
End With
```

You can also use this in an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx):

```
Dim usr1 As New DemoUsers With { .UserName = "name1", 
                                 .UserAddress = "Address1" }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim users As New List(Of DemoUsers)()
users.Add(New DemoUsers() With { _
    Key .UserName = "name1", _
    Key .UserAddress = "Address1" _
})
```

I used http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: That is a really ugly syntax.

Comment: @CodeCaster I edited the layout, Stack didn't catch the code at first. Otherwise, I'm just answering the OP's question who wants to know the VB shorthand that acts like the C# object initializer. I'm not trying to do art :)

Comment: That `Key` part is only for anonymous types, right? And this isn't an  anonymous type...

Comment: whats the key there? shows me an error? i tried the converter already

Comment: @naveen Look at Jon Skeet's answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is using a feature called [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

See this SO answer regarding [object initializers in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254219/444610).

Answer (score 0):

It's called an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx):

```
Dim cust1 As New Customer With {.Name = "Toni Poe", 
                                .City = "Louisville"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called object initializer syntax.

In VB

```
Dim usr1 As New DemoUsers() With
{
    .UserName = "name1",
    .UserAddress = "Address1"
}
```

Comment: You misses out the periods required for the `With`