# "End of statement expected" when creating a string list

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an "end of statement expected" error on the following code:

```
Public BlockedID As New List(Of String) From {"0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}
```

The code works fine on my nephew's version of Visual studios so I assume it's a VB.net framework specific problem. I already changed the target framework to 3.5 to get rid of some other errors.

Any idea how I can fix this one?

Comment: It's totally fine and compiles. Are you sure that's the line compiler complains about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net Object Initialiser List(Of T)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254169/vb-net-object-initialiser-listof-t): **introduced in VB.Net 2010**

Comment: Yeah, it's the line. It underlines the From {"0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"} part as being the problem.

Comment: Ok the problem in the link provided is probably the issue as I'm running VisualStudios 2008.

Now when I try     
Public BlockedID() As String
    BlockedID(0)="0"
    BlockedID(1)="2"
    BlockedID(3)="3"
    BlockedID(4)="4"
    BlockedID(5)="5"
    BlockedID(6)="6"

I'm getting a "declaration expected" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Public BlockedID As New List(Of String)({"0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"})
```